# Reusing function results in Python dict

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following (very simplified) dict. The `get_details` function is an API call that I would like to avoid doing twice.

```
ret = { 
    'a': a,
    'b': [{
        'c': item.c,
        'e': item.get_details()[0].e,
        'h': [func_h(detail) for detail in item.get_details()],
    } for item in items]
}
```

I could of course rewrite the code like this:

```
b = []
for item in items:
    details = item.get_details()
    b.append({
        'c': item.c,
        'e': details[0].e,
        'h': [func_h(detail) for detail in details],
    })

ret = { 
    'a': a,
    'b': b
}
```

but would like to use the first approach since it seems more pythonic.

Comment: on your second snippet, `details` are initialized based on `item` (whatever that is at that point..) but then `item` changes in the loop but `details` do not. Is that intended or false or simply bad variable naming ?

Comment: I think `details` is supposed to be inside the for loop in the second snippet.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis: It was an error of mine when trying to simplify existing code base. Thank you!

Comment: @BrendanGoggin: You are totally right, corrected code now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't find the second one particularly un-pythonic; you have a complex initialization, and you shouldn't expect to boil down to a single simple expression. That said, you don't need the temporary list `b`; you can work directly with `ret['b']`:

```
ret = { 
    'a': a,
    'b': []
}

for item in items:
    details = item.get_details()
    d = details[0]
    ret['b'].append({
        'c': item.c,
        'e': d.e,
        'h': map(func_h, details)
    })
```

This is also a case where I would choose `map` over a list comprehension. (If this were Python 3, you would need to wrap that in an additional call to `list`.)

Comment: without being very different this seems much more readable and neat. +1

Comment: I'll note I could go either way with using `d = details[0]`. One moment I think the extra line is worth the less-cluttered dict literal, the next I think the indirection makes it less clear.

Comment: how about a third option `d, *rest = item.get_details()` and then `'h': map(func_h, [b] + rest)`? not sure how this used to work with Python 2.7 (or even if...)

Comment: That's Python 3 syntax. If this *were* Python 3, though, you might write `d, *_ = details = item.get_details()` to get the first and all the elements in one (chained) assignment. Then there's no extra cost to recombine the head with the tail when setting `h`.

Comment: (The chained assignment is reminiscent of Haskell's at-pattern syntax, which would allow something like `let details@(d:_) = get_details item in ...`.)

Comment: Accepting this answer although @khelwwod's answer was more of what I first sought for. The non simplified dict would still be very cluttered, whereas this solution makes the code much more readable. Also, using mapping makes it even more readable.

Answer (score 6):

You could use an intermediary generator to extract the details from your items. Something like this:

```
ret = { 
    'a': a,
    'b': [{
        'c': item.c,
        'e': details[0].e,
        'h': [func_h(detail) for detail in details],
    } for (item, details) in ((item, item.get_details()) for item in items)]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't try too hard to be more pythonic if it means looking like your first approach. I would take your second approach a step further, and just use a separate function:

```
ret = {
    'a': a,
    'b': get_b_from_items(items)
}
```

I think that's as clean as it can get. Use comments/docstrings to indicate what `'b'` is, test the function, and then the next person who comes along can quickly read and trust your code. I know you know how to write the function, but for the sake of completeness, here's how I would do it:

```
# and add this in where you want it
def get_b_from_items(items):
    """Return a list of (your description here)."""
    result = []
    for item in items:
        details = item.get_details()
        result.append({
            'c': item.c,
            'e': details[0].e,
            'h': [func_h(detail) for detail in details],
        })
    return result
```

That is plenty pythonic (note the docstring-- very pythonic), and very readable. And of course, it has the advantage of being slightly more granularly testable, complex logic abstracted away from the higher level logic, and all the other advantages of using functions.

Comment: Why the downvote, please provide feedback in a comment if you can

Comment: i did not dv but it seems to me that you simply created a function that **hides** the mess rather than **cleans** it up.

Comment: @Ev. Kounis thanks for the response. Not quite how I'd phrase it, but yeah that's basically what I'm suggesting: Use comments and the function name to indicate what that `b` value is, but move the logic out of the main progession. As long as it works, and the next guy who comes along (even if it is the original programmer at a later date) can quickly understand what the `b` value is, I think that moving the mess out of the way is a good thing, and more pythonic than putting the code in the way (that being said, @khelwood's answer is pretty pretty).